# Allowed memory size exhausted after importing PO file

Tags: 7, features, i18n-l10n

I have a problem after importing the PO of the Drupal core 7.28 (I tried with French and Arabic), whenever I try to create a new feature or open the modules page, I will get an error:

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   5126472 bytes) in .../includes/form.inc on line 3906

After the import, it is consuming a lot of memory and time I tried debugging, this is the path I could trace:

```
menu_execute_active_handler -> drupal_get_form -> drupal_build_form -> features_export_form -> _features_export_form_components -> _features_export_build
```

This is as far as I could get while debugging. The last function `_features_export_build` takes a lot of time but I couldn’t know what is wrong inside.

Comment: Do you use features_translations module?

Comment: yes I do but this happens even before integrating anything with features

Comment: Not use it, it not working with many tranlsation strings. Better import translations throw 'po' files.

Comment: But now error exists because of features, yes?*

Comment: but how can I automatically integrate the po on install?

Answer (score 0):

Generating/exporting Feature modules takes a lot of memory, depending on amount of components which you're trying to export. The Features module is constantly improving, so please check the recent stable version if that makes the difference.

Otherwise you've to increase your PHP memory limit either in your `php.ini` or before the import, temporary add this line into your `settings.php` file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1G');
```

If you would like to debug what takes so much memory, then you need to use PHP profiler such as XDebug (`xdebug.profiler_enable=1`) or use [XHProf](https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).